# it it possible to solve these equation for their root.

Tags: optimization, roots, control-theory

I am trying to solve an equations such as the roots of $$k*x(11*x  + 1) + d*x(11x + 1)$$ has to match the roots of this function $$x^2  + 0.1x  + 6  +  k*x(11*x  + 1) + d*x(11x + 1)$$, where I have to solve values for k and d which match the criteria.

Is it even possible, I cannot seem to make mathmatica do it which make me question my method..

and What about for these for these

$$p*x  == x^2 + 0.1x+(6+p)$$

or

$$kp*x (11 x^2 + 1 x) + ki (11 x + 1x) +
  kd*x^2 (11x + 1 x) ==
 x (x^2 + 0.1 x + 6) + kp*x (11 x^2 + 1 x) +
  ki (11 x + 1 x) + kd*x^2 (11 x^2 + 1 x)$$

or

$$kp (11 x^2 + 1 x) +
  kd*x (11 x + 1 x) ==
 x (x^2 + 0.1 x + 6)  + kd*x(11 x^2 + 1 x)$$

one of them must be able to do so.

Comment: what's $ps$?  What do you mean by $ps == x^2 + 0.1x + 6 + p$?

Answer (score 1):

By factoring out $11x+1$ and $x$ the first function we find that it is equal to

$$
x (k+d)(11x+1),
$$

so its roots are $x=0$ and $x = -1/11$.

By expanding the parentheses then collecting like powers of $x$ we find that the second function is equal to

$$
(1+11k+11d)x^2 + (k + d + 0.1) x + 6.
$$

In order for this to have a root at $x = 0$ the constant term must be zero.  Since it isn't, and since the constant term doesn't depend on $k$ or $d$ (it's just $6$), it doesn't have a root at $x = 0$ no matter what $k$ and $d$ are.